# Downloading a file from Server FTP in Google Chrome using Intent in an android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, android-intent, ftp

I want to open a file from server FTP using intent for google chrome of the android device. On launching the app, it opens google chrome but does not search for the URL. Is it because I am specifying "ftp://" instead of "http://" in the URL. It has always worked when I have specified "http://" in the URL. Any help would be appreciated.

This is how my code looks like:

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
final String url = "ftp://demo-user:demo-user@demo.wftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf/";
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(uri));

            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

When Using http:// infront of ftp:// in URL as

```
final String url ="http://ftp://demo-user:demo-user@demo.wftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf/"
```

it launches google chrome and searches for ftp//demo-user:demo-user@demo.wftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf/

Whereas it should search for ftp://demo-user:demo-user@demo.wftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf/

Comment: are you sure that google chrome supports ftp:// scheme?

Comment: Not sure, maybe it doesn't. But what should I do if I want to see a file on ftp server using intent? If I copy & paste  " ftp://demo-user:demo-user@demo.wftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf/ " in google chrome, then it shows the wanted file. Whereas from the app it doesnt launch, it just opens google chrome but does not fire any URL. Maybe because I used ftp:// scheme.

Comment: try passing url without FTP scheme

Comment: You should at least url encode url.

Comment: `......manual_en.pdf/";` You should remove that slash. Its no folder is it?

Comment: `in google chrome, then it shows the wanted file.` On your PC? Chrome on an Android device cannot display pdf files. If you use that ftp url in Chrome then it just downloads the pdf. Just did that.

Comment: Try uri= Uri.parse(url);

Comment: Your code lets Chrome download the pdf. Thats what happens. Why didnt you tell?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do, which is download the pdf file using google chrome intent. But it doesn't download the file automatically. Even on using url encode it simply opens chrome on the device but does not fire any url search.

Comment: And on using `(i.setData(Uri.parse(url));` the app crashes as soon as we click something.

Comment: What should I do @greenapps??

Comment: On how many devices did you test? And on which Android versions?

Comment: `Yes that's what I want to do, which is download the pdf file using google chrome intent.` The subject of your post and your post do not agree.

Comment: I removed those two addFlags() and replaced by one setFlag(). For the rest i used your code unchanged.

Comment: I am currently using android studio version 3.0.1, and my device version were "5.0.1" and "4.4.1", I tried it on 3 of my Samsung devices.

Comment: I replaced two addFlags() by one setFlag(), but still the same problem continues. Google Chrome launches but does not search for any URL.

Comment: @greenapps can you please paste your working code down below?

Comment: `I removed those two addFlags() and replaced by one setFlag(). For the rest i used your code unchanged. `

Comment: @greenapps should I need something to add to my manifest.xml file? This is how it looks: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="*" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>`.

Comment: No. There is no reason to do so. You are only starting Chrome. You do not want to start an activity of your own app with that intent i think. You only wanna start Chrome.